# Automatic translation

Tags: autohotkey, google-translate

im really new to all this and i was trying to make an Autohotkey for translation. i was digging for some time looking for examples that only confused me more, even if the code looked simple, i didn't understand half of it.

So, what I'm trying to do is: select a paragraph and replace it automatically with its translation.

i was hooping it to be somenthing as simple as CTRJ + C, Translate, CTRL + V, but i can't find the command to go to google translate or somenthing similar, it's not on the autohotkey help file so i'm guessing i don't have libraries?

I'm at my wits end, please help.

Comment: How were you digging? googling for "autohotkey translate" gives you https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=63835 as first result just copy paste and you have a function with which you can translate

Comment: yes i saw that, and the next 4 or 5, they are all different and not commented at all so i can't learn anything. Besides, this is the first attemp at something larger, i need to understand it so i can improve it. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You came to the right place.  Check out AutoHotKey for sure.

First, how to do it by hand? Those are the steps for ahk. So, lets say you have a paragraph of text selected. You will hit the ahk shortcut and that shortcut will:

1. first ahk figures out what window its in (using `WinGetActiveTitle`) and then sends the keystrokes Ctrl+c to copy the selection ("`send, ^c`" and "`Clipwait`"), then
2. ahk can access the clipboard containing the text, do a string manipulation or regex to replace all spaces with the html escape sequence %20 (eg, `transtext := StrReplace(Clipboard, " ", "%20")`) and
3. construct a URL to do the Google Translate, something like (where **sl** is source language and **tl** is translation language, and **text** is what you want translated): `transurl := "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=es&text=" . transtext`
4. AHK runs that url and opens a browser window showing result (`run % transurl`).
5. This part sucks. Now, you need to use a mouse `click` at a location (or maybe you can find a `controlsend` or a combination of keystrokes moving the cursor with tabs and such) to land on the "Copy translation" button. Or how bout you do it manually (try `sleep, 8000` to wait while you hit the button)
6. then have ahk close the window (optionally, or you just do it by hand during the sleep time) and
7. ahk switches back to the application with the original selected paragraph (`WinActivate` or do it yourself) and
8. send ctrl+v to paste the translated text over the original (`send ^v`).

A starter pack of AHK code (edited per user comments):

```
WinGetActiveTitle, activewin
Clipboard =
SendInput, ^c
ClipWait
transtext := StrReplace(Clipboard, " ", "%20")
transurl := "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=es&text=" . transtext
Run, % transurl
Sleep, 6000 ; adjust to taste.
SendEvent, {tab 10} ; adjust to taste.
Sleep 1000
SendInput, {enter}
Sleep, 1000
SendInput, ^{F4}
WinActivate, activewin
sleep, 1000
SendInput, ^v
```

Try it and let us know how else to help.

Comment: Would recommend some translate api. Google offers one as well. Would offer the ability to create a one press solution.

Answer (score 0):

OKOK, first of all, thank you all, the script works just fine now. I'm able to copy, translate and paste any text now. Only a few questions lingering. 
1) i'm not sure i get what the step number 5 is suppose to do. whatever it is, it works so i don't touch it.
2) is there a way to reset google.translate so it dosent open a new window every time? that could save a lot of time.
3) this one doesn't have a chance, but i ask anyway. Is there a way to not open google chrome at all? because i know that u can translate from excel automatically. (i know that if it is possible will be super hard)

This is the code i ended with:

```
^a::
clipboard := ""
sendinput, ^c
ClipWait [,,Waitforanydata]
transtext := StrReplace(Clipboard, " ", "%20")
transurl := "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=es&text=" . 
transtext
run % transurl
Sleep, 4000
SendEvent, {tab 9}
SendEvent, {enter}
Winactivate, NAME.pdf - PROGRAM
sendinput, ^v
```